# Changing ActionBar background color programatically from a preference

Tags: android, android-actionbar, color-picker

I've added a color picker preference to the settings in my app so the user can pick the background color of the `ActionBar` (I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`).  Ideally I'd like to change the color without having the user restart the app which, I'm assuming, means adding the code to change the color in `onResume` in every `Activity` and `Fragment`.  However, the color change works when I first hit an activity, but if I go back to it, either using the back button on my device or in the `ActionBar` itself, the color seems to not be set and is transparent.

This is the code I'm using to set the background color.  I tried adding it to `onCreate` as well as `onResume`:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {

   @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);        
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("app_color", getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color))));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    { 
        super.onResume();

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("app_color", getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color))));
    }
}
```

`app_color` is the name of the color picker preference and also have a default color, stored in the `colors` value file.  I also have a `TextView` footer that doesn't have the same issue and retains the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and what i came up with is probably not the best solution but at least works for me for the time being. I check in onRestart with the following method if the theme has changed (in your app you would check if the background color has changed) and if so I start the activity as in the following code snippet. In my app I put this method in the application class as i use it in every activity.

```
public static void restartOnThemeSwitch(Activity act) {

    String currentTheme = getThemeName(act.getTheme());

    String prefTheme = (prefs.getString(THEME, "dark"));

    if (currentTheme.equalsIgnoreCase(prefTheme) == false) {


        Intent it = act.getIntent();
        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        act.startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I misspoke, hitting the back button in the `ActionBar` does retain the color, which make sense since it's basically doing what you're doing and starting a new activity.  I might just have a message for the user to restart the app for the change to take effect.  Doesn't look like there is a perfect solution.  Thanks.

Comment: probably different cases yet with the above posted quote the user can change the theme in the preferences in my app and all back etc navigation will show the activities in the newly chosen theme - asking to restart seems not that elegant ... ;-)